# Check list or strings to see if a string from another list is present

Tags: python, string, list, find

I have a list of strings in ListA, and I need to check if any string from listA is in the ith element of listB. If yes, I need to append a string to listB.

For example

```
ListA =  [['Chicago'], ['Rockford'], ['Aurora']]

ListB = [['Town', 'Population', 'ZipCode'], ['Chicago Heights', '250,000', '12345'], ['Dallas', '1,700,000', '23456']]
```

If any string in ListA, is at some point of the string in ListB[0-2][0], I need to append another string to end of the ListB[0-2].

The output would be

```
ListC = [['Town', 'Population', 'ZipCode','not illinois'], ['Chicago Heights', '250,000', '12345', Illinois], ['Dallas', '1,700,000', '23456','not Illinois']]
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you could benefit from a more sensible data structure here, e.g. a `dict`, but this basically does what you've asked:

```
for x in ListB:
    for y in x:
        if any(s in y for [s] in ListA):
            x.append('Illinois')
            break
    else:
        x.append('not Illinois')
```

Note:  this method mutates `ListB` in place, rather than creating a new `ListC`.